# Hermite Polynomial Expansion

Tags: integration, numerical-methods, hermite-polynomials

Suppose I have expanded the function $f(x)$ in Hermite polynomials,
\begin{equation}
a_n = \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)\exp(-x^2)\mathcal{H}_n(x)dx \,.
\end{equation}

How can I express the expansion coefficients for $f(\sqrt{x^2+\alpha^2})$ in terms of coefficients $a_n$?

Comment: The integrals are over the whole real line?

Comment: Why are you sure a compact way to express the new coefficients exists anyway?

Comment: Yes, as shown here:
[https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermite_polynomials]